# Windows 7 Driver for Print to XPS

Tags: windows, drivers, xps, wdk

The link to the Windows 7 DDK (or WDK) is not something I seem to be able to get to.
I need to write a driver that will convert the content to XPS and then do something with it. The "do something" is easy, but its the first part I'm not sure of.

I found links to the Win7 WDK but as I said above I can't get to it (my company has MSDN but I can't find it in the downloads).

As for the XPS part, I found [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/wdkdocs/archive/2009/07/10/xps-document-api-now-available-for-printer-driver-filter-modules.aspx) which talks about XPS now available, and the resulting link to [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd316976(VS.85).aspx) doesn't seem to focus on drivers at all and seems more general.

I'm wondering if anyone can help with these two issues. Is writing a driver for Win7 much the same as Vista, in which case I can at least get started with the Windows 2008 WDK? And has anyone used this XPS filter pipeline to print to XPS with their own custom drivers?

Appreciate all help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a link to the Windows Driver Kit (WDK) 7.0.0 on the [How to get the WDK page](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/wdk/WDKpkg.mspx).

For driver development, XPSDrv drivers developed for Vista (and the downlevel redist for XP & Server 2003) are compatible with Windows 7. However, Windows 7 adds new Win32 APIs that can be used within an XPSDrv and help with manipulating XPS content and provide a driver-safe rasterization capability.